# Universal family of Hibert shemes of Points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology

My question is how to explicitly compute the Chern class of the universal sheaf of the moduli space of ideal sheaves of two and three points on a given smooth projective variety X (no need to be algebraic surface) ?
When we consider the two points case, the cohomology ring of the moduli can be explictly written down, I hope to represent the Chern class of the universal sheaf in terms of some element of cohomology ring of moduli and base manifold X.